# Prevent incompatibilities by choosing distinct names for binaries

Tags: windows, dll, bin

You often see that developers have a "bin32" and "bin64" output folder for their software projects, and within these folders live the built executable files, usually called `<project_name>.exe` and something like `<project_name>_d.exe` for debug builds. It seemed kind of strange to me, so I began to wonder if there is any reason to name your 32 and 64 bit binaries the same for release and debug builds, only separating them by placing them in different folders.

The following quote, taken from [this msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), concerns me:

> If a DLL with the same module name is already loaded in memory, the system uses the loaded DLL, no matter which directory it is in. The system does not search for the DLL.

Assume I have a project called `X` in 32 and 64 bit builds. While running the 32 bit version of `X.exe`, which uses `X_core.dll` in 32 bit, I start the 64 bit version of `X.exe`. According to the msdn article above, the system tries to execute the 64 bit version of `X.exe` dynamically linking to the 32 bit version of `X_core.dll`.

It seems kind of odd and dangerous to me to simply compare `dlls` by name. Isn't this a good reason to name binaries more distinctly, like `<project_name>32.dll`, `<project_name>64.dll` for release builds and `<project_name>_d32.dll`, `<project_name>_d64.dll` for debug builds?

Note: I do understand why one would name their debug builds differently than their release builds. Mainly, I would just like to know why it is so common to separate 32 and 64 bit builds, but not debug and release builds.

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. A 64-bit process will never use a 32-bit DLL, even if it is already in memory, and likewise a 32-bit process will never use a 64-bit DLL. The naming differences are usually so you can easily tell which version you're distributing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 64bit process cannot load a 32bit DLL, and vice versa.  In the MSDN article you linked to, the "memory" it is referring to is the "calling process's memory".  A process can load only one instance of a compatible (same bitness) DLL module at a time.

Comment: If there are multiple instance of `X.dll` in the search path, will a 64 bit process favor the first 64 bit version of `X.dll` or is it even able to load a non-64 bit version of `X.dll`?

Comment: "A 64bit process cannot load a 32bit DLL", thought that was pretty clear. Whether a 64bit process will ignore 32bit DLLs and keep looking, or will just load the first DLL it finds and fail if it is 32bit, I do not know, never tried it before.